# Цикл внутри цикла

Tags: javascript

Собрал вот такую конструкцию. Вроде проста. Но работать не хочет. Почему?

```
var weights = [];

function initialize_weights() {
    var array_weights = [];
    var w = 0;
    for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        for(w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
            array_weights[w] = n + "_" + w;
        }
        weights[n] = array_weights;
    }
}
```

Конечный массив должен выглядеть так:

> [ '0_0', '0_1', '0_2', '0_3', '0_4' ], [ '1_0', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3',
>   '1_4' ], [ '2_0', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4' ]

Но он почему-то выглядит так:

> [ '2_0', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4' ], [ '2_0', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3',
>   '2_4' ], [ '2_0', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4' ]

Что-то не так с переменной **n**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function initialize_weights() {
  var weights = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    var array_weights = [];
    for (var w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
      array_weights.push(n + '_' + w);
    }
    weights.push(array_weights);
  }
  return weights;
}
var weights = initialize_weights();
console.log(weights);
```

Без использования `push()`:

```js
var weights = [];
function initialize_weights() {
  for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    var array_weights = [];
    for (var w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
      array_weights[w] = n + "_" + w;
    }
    weights[n] = array_weights;
  }
}
initialize_weights();
console.log(weights);
```